# how to replace specific character from string in jQuery

Tags: jquery, string

I have the string in jQuery like:

```
<select id='orderlist-0' name='orderitems[0].orderitem.OrderItemId'></select>
<span class='field-validation-valid' 
      data-valmsg-for='orderitems[0].orderitem.OrderItemId' 
      data-valmsg-replace='true'></span>
```

Now I want to replace all the 0's in [] with 1's. Which is the easy and efficient method ?

Comment: The HTML mark-up you've posted is the string you're working with? Or does the string come from elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to search and replace in strings.

```
var str,
    re;

str = "<select id='orderlist-0' name='orderitems[0].orderitem.OrderItemId'></select><span class='field-validation-valid' data-valmsg-for='orderitems[0].orderitem.OrderItemId' data-valmsg-replace='true'></span>";

re = /(\[)(0)(\])/g;

str = str.replace(re, '$11$3');
```

- [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/xc2HE/)
- [**Documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var s="your string here"
    var result=s.replace(/0/g, '1');
```